# Can we autoplay a embeded video with sound using Youtube Iframe API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have observed that videos on WhatsApp and Inshorts are automatically playing with sound. How can we achieve this functionality using the Iframe Player API?

```
 new YT.Player("player", {
          videoId: "sGPrx9bjgC8",
          playerVars: {
            playsinline: 1,
            autoplay: 1,
            color: "blue",
            mute: 0,
            enablejsapi: 1,
            loop: 1
          },
          events: {
            onReady: onPlayerReady
          }
        })
```

this doesn't worked

Comment: Are you referring to cell phones or tablets?